# Помогите составить запрос MySQL для сравнение заголовков таблиц

Tags: mysql

Добрый вечер. Подскажите пожалуйста запрос для того, чтобы сравнить названия всех колонок (кроме перечисленных в отдельной переменной) и записать в третию таблицу, вида value, status в колонку value названия ячеки, которая отсутствует во второй таблице и установить в колонку status 1, и аналогично, в колонку value название колонки, которая есть во второй таблице, но нет в первой и установить в колонку status цифру 0.

Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Навскидку так:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (old, new)
SELECT CASE flag WHEN 1 THEN COLUMN_NAME ELSE '' END,
       CASE flag WHEN 2 THEN COLUMN_NAME ELSE '' END
FROM ( SELECT COLUMN_NAME, SUM(CASE TABLE_NAME
                               WHEN 'table1' THEN 1
                               WHEN 'table2' THEN 2
                               END) flag
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database'
         AND TABLE_NAME IN ('table1', 'table2')
       GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
       HAVING flag < 3 
     ) dummy
```

Comment: А куда указать название колонок, которые сравнивать не надо? Как я понимаю - ELSE '' END ?

Comment: Спасибо большое, запрос сработал. И можно внести небольшое изменение - записать в таблицу 3, как у Вас тут приведено, в первую колонку - название, а во вторую цифру - или 1 или 0, взамен old new.

Comment: *И можно внести небольшое изменение* Внесите самостоятельно. Уберите обёртку вокруг внутреннего SELECT, поменяйте местами флаги 1 и 2, и вычитайте единицу при INSERT.